# Prevent Direct Access Form Success Page in PHP

Tags: php, jquery

i am saving register form data through PHP jQuery something like

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#FORM_ID").submit(function() {
                var name= $("#name").val();
                var password= $("#password").val();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "insert.php",
                    data: "name=" + name+ "&password=" + password,
                    success: function(data) {
                       alert("sucess");
                    }
                });


            });
    });
</script>
```

problem is if i directly access insert.php and pass parameter on url its saving data , and on form submittion i am doing some verification so by doing this anyone can directly save register data and can bypass verification easily so any other way to prevent this.

Comment: There are checks that you can use to see if the request is an ajax request and then you can redirect the user. You can also go for a .htaccess file blocking direct access from outside of the server.

Comment: @AaronNoHuanKnows thanks , does any suggest link , if any please give ?

Comment: I'm sure you're able to find it yourself through Google now.

Comment: @AaronNoHuanKnows ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'){
  exit();
}
```

Place this on top of your `insert.php` file. This will check if the posted data is via AJAX or via from a form. If the posted data is from AJAX it will allow further execution. Else, it will exit the execution then and there if the condition is not met (or false).

Comment: this error Fatal error: 'continue' not in the 'loop' or 'switch' context

Comment: remove continue and try.. I have updated the answer.

Comment: If `exit;` doesn't respond, try `exit();`. It sometimes happen!

Comment: You should let him figure it out, i gave enough comments to put him in the right path, spoonfeeding won't teach anyone anything.

Comment: @AaronNoHuanKnows You are not half wrong but I think he is a very beginner. Sometimes, even spoon feeding is necessary. It helps too. Every individual is different and learns at at their own pace and method. Also, you didn't help anything. You only wrote 2 comments. One in which you gave the logic and other just asking him to google on his own. This is Stack Overflow mate! Here, you help with code. Or at least suggest link to an answer or article? If he had to search on his own he could do that without anyone suggesting him I guess. And I believe he did that already.

Comment: @Tausif did my answer help?

Comment: @ShubhamJha thanks helped, and i  like research but this time i have really lots of work and less time so i was just need solution , this time i cant R&D for 10-20 also , else i love to find the solutions. well thanks both of you ShubhamJha and AaronNoHuanKnows

Comment: @Tausif most welcome... glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

The simple way for me to do this by using variable can read between server side and client side like `cookie, localstorage , session` in the next example I use session for this

```
$_SESSION['token'] = md5(uniqid()); //<<<< set the session 
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#FORM_ID").submit(function() {
      var name= $("#name").val();
      var password= $("#password").val();

      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "insert.php",
         data: {
             name : name,
             password : password,
             token : '<?php echo $_SESSION['token']; ?>' //<<< pass the session
         },
         success: function(data) {
             alert("sucess");
         }
      });
   });
});
</script>
```

Then in php you can use

```
session_start(); // don't forget to start the session here
if($_POST['token'] === $_SESSION['token']){  // check for the session
  // success here
}
```

Comment: Sorry @Tausif my bad , Need to use `<?php echo $_SESSION['token'];  ?>` because it a php variable and don't forget to start the session .. answer updated